# The relative Frobenius morphism $F_{X/S}$ is an isomorphism iff $X/S$ is étale?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, etale-cohomology

The statement comes from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism), see the picture below.
[image]

I know that if $X$ is étale over $S$ then $F_{X/S}$ is an isomorphism and a proof can be found [here](https://lovelylittlelemmas.rjprojects.net/relative-frobenius/). But is the reverse true? I believe that I have found a counter example.

Let $R$ be a domain of characteristic $p$ and $F$ be its fraction field. Denote the Frobenius map $F_R:R\to R'$ which is injective for a domain. Denote $S=R-0$. Then
$$F\otimes_{R} R'=(S^{-1}R)\otimes_R R' =(F_R (S))^{-1}R'=(S^p)^{-1}R'$$
But $(S^p)^{-1}R'=S^{-1}R'=F'$ since $\frac{1}{t}=\frac{t^{p-1}}{t^p}$. So $F\otimes_R R'=F'$. Explicitly the relative Frobenius map $F_{F/R}:F\otimes_R R'\to F',\frac{u}{v}\otimes t\mapsto \frac{u^p t}{v^p}$ has an inverse $\phi:F'\to F\otimes_R R',\frac{x}{y}\mapsto \frac{1}{y}\otimes y^{p-1}x$.
Now we just need to show there exists a characteristic $p$ domain $R$ s.t. $R\hookrightarrow F$ is not étale.

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $p$, and we consider the localization $R=K[x]\hookrightarrow K(x)=F$ which is not finitely generated (if so then $K(x)$ is finitely generated over $K$, contradiction), hence not étale.

Comment: I believe the statement is only true for $X/S$ locally of finite type (presentation?) and that your counterexample is correct minus this hypothesis.

Comment: Yes. The counterexample you construct is an example of a so called weakly etale map and for all those the relative Frobenius is an isomorphism. What is true, is that for a map $X\to S$, for which the relative Frobenius is an isomorphism, the cotangent complex is zero (as pulling back differential forms along relative Frobenius is now an isomorphism, but the differential of Frobenius is zero because of $d(X^{p})=pX^{p-1}dX=0$). When your map is of finite presentation, vanishing of the cotangent complex is equivalent to being etale.

Comment: @Rieux It seems convincing but I am not familar with cotangent complex, is there a way to see this without using cotangent complex?